# Get all the last message from each friend - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select last message from each friend just like how all other chatting applications do. Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT m.message, 
                   m.message_read,
                   m.message_date,
                   CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                        THEN m.receiver
                        ELSE m.sender
                   END as friend_id,
                   CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                        THEN p2.nickname
                        ELSE p1.nickname
                   END as name,
                   CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                        THEN p2.image
                        ELSE p1.image
                   END as image
            FROM message as m
            JOIN profile as p1
              ON m.sender = p1.user_id    -- sender
            JOIN profile as p2 
              ON m.receiver = p2.user_id  -- receiver
            WHERE 4 IN (m.sender, m.receiver)
```

Above select statement gets

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| message   | message_read | message_date        | friend_id | name  | image |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Hey Buddy |            1 | 2018-05-10 11:58:39 |         1 | JUAN  | NULL  |
| SUP MATE  |            1 | 2018-05-15 11:04:24 |         1 | JUAN  | NULL  |
| nooo      |            1 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |         2 | user3 | NULL  |
| lulz      |            1 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |         2 | user3 | NULL  |
| shut up   |            1 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |         2 | user3 | NULL  |
| heha      |            1 | 2018-05-15 10:36:11 |         2 | user3 | NULL  |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

I am specifically using message_date variable from message table to sort these messages out.

message table:

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | sender | receiver | message   | message_read | message_visible | message_date        |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      4 |        2 | lulz      |            1 |               2 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |
|  2 |      1 |        4 | Hey Buddy |            1 |            NULL | 2018-05-10 11:58:39 |
|  3 |      2 |        4 | nooo      |            1 |               2 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |
|  4 |      4 |        2 | shut up   |            1 |               2 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |
|  5 |      4 |        2 | heha      |            1 |            NULL | 2018-05-15 10:36:11 |
|  6 |      1 |        4 | SUP MATE  |            1 |            NULL | 2018-05-15 11:04:24 |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to get the result of

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| message   | message_read | message_date        | friend_id | name  | image |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| SUP MATE  |            1 | 2018-05-15 11:04:24 |         1 | JUAN  | NULL  |
| heha      |            1 | 2018-05-15 10:36:11 |         2 | user3 | NULL  |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Please help me to figure this out. Any comment will be helpful! This should also take same message_date into consideration. e.g. if there are two messages with exact same date/time, then only one should be chosen among them. I am thinking about id of message table to choose which one among them.

Comment: This would be easy in any modern db (just do lateral join/apply). Sadly, MySql hasn't qualified as "modern" for over a decade now, so you'll have to do something much more complicated.

Comment: Also... how possible is it _really_ for the same person to send two messages in the same tick/microsecond? If you only store down the second, that could be a problem, but a reasonable DateTime field handling timestamps has more precision than that.

Comment: @ibrahimShendy It just happens to be that they were chronological. I did not have ORDER BY m.message_date for above statement.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Coincidence happens once in a while. I just want to figure out a way to safeguard from all other odds that somehow exist.

Comment: Of course it's possible to have to messages at the same time... but from the _same user_ to the _same friend_? That's some fast clicking.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn hella correct. I ain't thinking correct. You right!! I am talking about the user1 -> user2 message and user2 -> user1 message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat like

```
select m.*
from 
message m
left join message m1 on (
  (
    (m.sender = m1.sender and m.receiver = m1.receiver)
                          or
    (m.sender = m1.receiver and m.receiver = m1.sender )
  )
   and case when m.message_date = m1.message_date
            then m.id < m1.id
            else m.message_date < m1.message_date
       end
)
where m1.id is null
and 4 in(m.sender, m.receiver)
```

I have added `case` expression to check if there are more than 1 messages on same date time then pick the latest message on basis of id, I assume id is set to auto-increment.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb14b8/6)

Comment: I am trying to understand this query. What is the reason of having "where m1.id is null"?

Comment: @John It's called an exclusion join. Join the table to itself where you match on newer records, and only keep rows where a newer record does not exist (is null).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you for the clarification!! It is a very tricky concept. Your explanation is very succinct and clear. I guess I need to get used to it.

Answer (score -1):

use row_number and partition by.

```
select * from
(SELECT m.message, 
               m.message_read,
               m.message_date,
               CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                    THEN m.receiver
                    ELSE m.sender
               END as friend_id,
               CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                    THEN p2.nickname
                    ELSE p1.nickname
               END as name,
               CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                    THEN p2.image
                    ELSE p1.image
               END as image,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY friend_id ORDER BY m.message_date DESC) AS rn               
        FROM message as m
        JOIN profile as p1
          ON m.sender = p1.user_id    -- sender
        JOIN profile as p2 
          ON m.receiver = p2.user_id  -- receiver
        WHERE 4 IN (m.sender, m.receiver)
) t
where rn=1
```

Comment: I have not seen "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY friend_id ORDER BY m.message_date DESC) AS rn". There is a version clash when I run this query. Thanks for your comment!!

Comment: This is for Sql Server... but any modern DB can do it, including Oracle and Postgresql. Sadly, as I said earlier, MySql doesn't fit that category any more.

Comment: Joel is a bit out of touch. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html